# Old Grub loader still in use

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

My computer came with Windows 7. I later erased the disk and clean installed Debian. Later, I needed Windows so again did a Windows 7 clean install and then installed Debian. Then, I installed the latest Ubuntu and deleted the old Debian in the process.

But when I start my computer now, the (old, debian) boot menu shows:

```
Windows 7
Debian Linux
```

If I choose Windows 7, I boot into W7, no issues, but when I choose Debian, the computer shows the latest ubuntu's boot loader:

```
Ubuntu
Ubuntu with options
*some other option*
windows 7
```

If I choose Windows 7 here, I'm again taken to the first boot loader screen and not boot into windows 7.

Screenshot of Gparted:

[image]

What should I do now, to remove the old Grub and get the latest Grub loader booting into the windows7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct GRUB boot loader installed ! - You only see the old Windows boot menu entry, because the Windows BCD store has not been modified after you had installed Ubuntu.

Boot Windows and open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
bcdedit /enum all /v
```

Search for the debian boot entry menu ... copy the identifier and execute :

```
bcdedit /set {*} description "Ubuntu"
```

Replace the * with the copied identifier.

**Update (with instructions addressing the new information provided on December, 8 / 2015)**

First re-install the Windows boot loader.
Boot from Windows installation media and on **Install now** screen select **Repair your computer**.
Choose **Command prompt** and execute:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Then re-install the "Ubuntu" boot loader.
Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing** ... on desktop ...
Open a **terminal** and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : sda = disk | sda1 = Ubuntu system partition (taken from the screenshot in your question)

Comment: I think my question is confusing. Here's the summary: 
1. Debian + W7 dual boot
2. Removed Debian and Installed Ubuntu so Ubuntu + W7 dual boot.

Now, when I start my laptop, I see the old debian Grub(black screen white text) showing: W7 + Debian Linux
If I select W7 it boots into W7. no problems. If I select Debian, I see the Grub of Ubuntu(violet background and white text) with the 4 options mentioned in the question. It boots correctly into ubuntu from there but if I choose w7 there, I'm sent back to the previous debian boot loader.

Comment: Did you read previous comment after the recent edit? Sorry I'm still getting used to the site. It's not about the word "ubuntu". I'm saying the system has two boot loaders in there and I want to get rid of the old one. But since the newer boot loader from ubuntu installation still redirects me to the old boot loader if I select windows 7, without just booting into w7, can i actually delete the old boot loader without affecting my windows installation?